# Intersect Method Slows Down Code In Large Selection Of Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have picture in certain cells. When I run following code (With Intersect Method) in smaller number of selected cells, it runs correctly but when the number of selected cells increase - say above 1000, then code slows down a bit (Intersect Method). Can it be optimized? Code without intersect method runs Ok.Can intersect method further optimize the code?

**Code Without Intersect Method:**

```
Sub tagging3()
Dim rng As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Dim m As Long
Dim arr() As String
Dim sample As String

m = 1
ReDim arr(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    arr(m) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
    m = m + 1
Next

For Each rng In Selection
    sample = rng.Address
    rng.Offset(0, 30).Value = "No"
    For m = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
        If sample = arr(m) Then
              rng.Offset(0, 30).Value = "Yes"
              Exit For
        End If
    Next m
Next
End Sub
```

**Code With Intersect Method - Quite Slow**

```
Sub shapesincells()
Dim sh As Shape, isect, rng As Range, n As Integer, arr() As Variant, sample As String
ReDim arr(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
n = 1
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Set arr(n) = sh.TopLeftCell
        n = n + 1
Next
For Each rng In Selection
    sample = rng.Offset(0, 30).Address
    For n = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(arr(n), rng)
            If Not isect Is Nothing Then
               sample = "Yes"
            End If
    Next
    If IsEmpty(sample) Then sample = "No"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't check for an Intersect. I would check/compare if column and row is the same, since you are comparing cell vs cell. Or i would check/compare the address field.

Comment: Intersect method quite slow in such scenarios (large number of cells in selection) It compares objects directly (e.g. range object) rather than references to an objects (e.g. range addresses). Here we are simply interested in whether cell has object over it. So instead of using intersect to check cells themselves first, all cell addresses where object exist are stored in an array (first method above - code without intersect) and then each cell address in selected range is compared against each element of array and next steps of the code (flagging "Yes" or "No") in offset cell are carried out.